# 2-stoke motorcycle engine stops when shift to first gear

Tags: motorcycle, transmission, clutch

My Dt Lanza 230 has a problem, the engine idle is ok, but I when pull the clutch and shift into first gear, the engine stops. I mean,the engine idle is smooth, but the engine stops when I shift into first gear. So, I have to pull the throttle cable a little to prevent the engine from stopping. It is very embarrassing to me at the traffic light when the engine stops.

And I am aware that when I free the rear wheel from the ground and shift into first gear, the rear wheel rotates and I press the rear break and the engine stops again.

Any suggestion are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is just simple basic maintenance.  I don't know this bike, but in general:

Your clutch cable will have an adjuster, since the cable stretches in use over time, you can tighten it up to stop the clutch from dragging like this.

Instructions for the clutch cable adjustment should be in your owner's manual.

Comment: Another, more unlikely cause, compared to the above : is there a switch to detect neutral? if so is it correctly adjusted, but I think Frank B is correct.

Comment: Thk Frank, I adjust clutch cable almost the end. No problem for idle when gear 1 is swift. But tension too much. Anyway thk.

Comment: There might be two clutch adjusters, one on the hand lever and one on the engine case. Also, Is there a kickstand? I think Yamahas usually have a feature that kills the engine if you try to put it in gear with the kickstand down. Your kickstand switch might be faulty.